Is there a name for non sparse linear operators which are products of convolution-like all-but-oneunities?
Is there a name for non sparse linear operators which are products of convolution-like all-but-one unities?
I suppose I will have to apologize for the cryptic question phrasing, but I really could not find a better way to express it.
I believe that a simple example will explain what I am after.
Consider the discretized differential operator.
$$D = \left[\begin{array}{llllll}1&0&0&0&0&0\\-1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&-1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&-1&1\end{array}\right]$$
Which furthermore can be viewed as a convolution with [1,-1].
It's inverse is
$$S =  \left[\begin{array}{llllll}1&0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0\\1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1\end{array}\right]$$
Which is non-sparse.
However if we consider the convolution
$$S_i =  \left[\begin{array}{llllll}1&0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1&1\end{array}\right]$$
And we use it to create a product (from the left) like so we shall find
$$S = \prod {S_i}_k * I $$
if we furthermore define ${S_i}_k$ as the matrices Ms in the octave expression below:
D = diag(ones(6,1),0)-diag(ones(5,1),-1); S = inv(D); Si = abs(D); op = reshape(1:6,[1,1,6]); Ms = ([1:6]'==op).*Si + ([1:6]'!=op).*eye(6); Mat = eye(6);for i_=1:6; Mat = Ms(:,:,i_)*Mat; endfor;

Or in mathematics language : the rows of ${S_i}_k$ are equal to $S_i$ for the particular row $k$ and unity (just pasting values of $I$) everywhere else.
The octave matrix "Mat" is after this product equal to $S$.
So to my question : is there some mathematical word or notation for a product like this where the matrix we derive factors ${S_i}_k$ from is a convolutional matrix.
The reason for asking the question is that these occur everywhere you would model vectors with recurrence relations, apply them and efficiently express their inverses.
